# MySQL Hash Value as Column Name

Tags: mysql, md5, mysql-error-1064

I'm getting a syntax error when creating a table with the result of PHP's `md5(microtime())` as the column name.

In particular, the error is getting thrown at the part with ** surrounding it:

```
CREATE TABLE form_data_38 (
    id           INT SIGNED auto_increment NOT NULL,
    rltd_pri_key INT SIGNED NULL,
    0accc77c084cc74a51dee479f8d095e3   TEXT(65535) NOT NULL,
    **092e60b78f7804e86ea9a6e83701a929 TEXT(65535) NOT NULL**,
    6734131796201537410e4d43635bf1b3   TEXT(65535) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) TYPE=InnoDB;
```

What is confusing me is why it's being thrown at that spot and not the other 2 hash values prior to it.  I appended 'a' to the column names and it created the table no problem.  I've searched MySQL naming rules and so far I haven't come up with anything.  It just says all alphanumeric characters plus '_' and '$' are okay to use, which should be fine in this instance.

What am I missing?

Comment: I should also note that this has worked before with other hashed values.

Comment: If you found the answer, post it as an answer. If you don't have enough rep yet, keep contributing to SO to gain it then post it when you do! Thanks

Comment: Why on earth would you use a column name like this?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your table and field names in backquotes: `` `09e4_fieldName` ``, at least for those that can create such problems:

```
CREATE TABLE form_data_38 
  ( id INT SIGNED auto_increment NOT NULL 
  , rltd_pri_key INT SIGNED NULL 
  , `0accc77c084cc74a51dee479f8d095e3` TEXT(65535) NOT NULL 
  , `092e60b78f7804e86ea9a6e83701a929` TEXT(65535) NOT NULL 
  , `6734131796201537410e4d43635bf1b3` TEXT(65535) NULL 
  , PRIMARY KEY (id) 
  ) 
ENGINE = InnoDB ;                    --- ENGINE, not TYPE
```

Comment: The underlying issue ended up being that the column names were being rendered as scientific notation, as they had 'e##' in them (092**e60**b78f7804**e86**ea9a6e83701a929).  Encompassing the column name in backticks (or whatever provider-specific quotes are needed) passed the name in verbatim and wasn't being analyzed.